# Show elements from 2 collection side by side, using 2 ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 collection: names and values. 
How can I show it using bootstrap columns and agularjs like on image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztoPe.png)
I try this, but it doesn't give required result:

```
   <div class="row" >
      <div class="col-sm-6" ng-repeat="name in controller.names">
          <label>{{ name }}</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6" ng-repeat="value in controller.values">
          <label>{{ value }}</label>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Firstly it shows all names, and after all values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do one `ng-repeat` and show the label and names like shown below.

We loop through the names in the `ng-repeat` and use the `$index` variable of the looped array and select the respective value in the `$scope.values` array, let me know if this helps you!

I have added the `well` class the highlight the column location! you can remove it, if you want!

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
  $scope.names = ["name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5", "name6"];
  $scope.values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 well" ng-repeat="name in names" >
        <label for="">{{name}}</label><br>
        <label for="">{{values[$index]}}</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<div class="row" >
      <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div ng-repeat="name in controller.names">
              <label>{{ name }}</label>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div ng-repeat="value in controller.values">
              <label>{{ value }}</label>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

You're repeating columns instead of placing divs within said columns. This results in

```
[a][b]
[c][1]
[2][3]
```

instead of

```
[a][1]
[b][2]
[c][3]
```

---

**Extra solution:**
Build on the premise of the question, if you want the values to "stick together", so to say, with a particular value belonging to a particular name you might want a set up like:

```
controller.owners = [{name: "a", value: 1},{name: "b", value: 2},{name: "c", value: 3}];
```

With in your html:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="owner in controller.owners">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>{{owner.name}}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label>{{owner.value}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```